# Fireing a jquery function with timer tick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

So I have this jquery function

```
 function lbviewmore_click() {
            erAlert();
    }
```

I want if to be fired after a certain time so I created this.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    alerts = DBExecute("exec testingt ", cs);
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Tick);
    aTimer.Start();
}
protected void rawr()
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "blah", "lbviewmore_click();", true);
}
private void timer_Tick(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    rawr();
    alerts2 = DBExecute("exec testingt ", cs);
    if (alerts.Count == alerts2.Count)
    {

    }
    else
    {
    }
    //this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "test", "lbviewmore_click()", true);
    //System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    //aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Tick);
    //aTimer.Interval = 1000;
    //aTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

It runs if I put the clientscript within a button_click. But I want it in the else section. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you wanting this to popup after a certain time period regardless if the button is clicked or not..? if so then start here or do a google search on how to automatically popup alerts when no activity in a web page.. 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1899214.aspx?If+no+activity+for+15+minutes+display+an+alert+on+web+page+and+then+either+continue+or+logout

Comment: agreed requirement is poor, why are you mixing c# asp.net and Jquery, seems extremely odd... what you are trying to do.... did you at least do some search before asking this question

Comment: I don't want a button click. When I place "rawr();" into pageload the jquery runs fine or if I place it inside of a button. But I want this jquery to run every 25 secs. I have it set to 5 secs right now for testing. It will also be in the else but again for purpose of testing it's outside of the if else statement.

Comment: I have done a lot of research and all I have found is people wanting it to work with a button. I looked up reasons why the timer will not call the function but still have yet to really find anything.

Comment: @MethodMan See I've seen that but my goal here is this. My c# code runs a proc that looks at the count of rows in db. If the count changes then I run the jquery that pops up with an alert saying "there was a change" on the web page.

Comment: you need to do some polling and this is possible we currently do this using  `AngularJS`

Comment: I have continued to do a lot more searching and still nothing. What I did find though is that it has something to do with the ElapsedEventHandler. I've looked at ways to try to fix it but they are all for windows applications and not web applications. So I am still at a standstill on how to do this >.<. Thank you everyone though for your help it kind of made me try to think about it another way. I will try to keep everyone updated and if I figure it out on Monday I will put an answer. If anyone can think of another way to implement my way other than a timer that would be good too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to use viewstate as well with updatepanels and ajax timer.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "erAlert", "lbviewmore_click();", true);
```

I am using Scriptmanager to run the javascript.
I was trying to avoid ajax but it seemed to be the best way to do it.
Thank you everyone who chipped in ideas. Hopefully this helps the next person who comes a long.

```
  protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["alert"]);
    alerts2 = DBExecute("exec testingt ", cs);
    if (x == alerts2.Count)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "erAlert", "lbviewmore_click();", true);
        alerts = DBExecute("exec testingt ", cs);
        int userdata = alerts.Count;
        ViewState["alert"] = userdata;
    }
}

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack)
    {
        alerts = DBExecute("exec testingt ", cs);
        int userdata = alerts.Count;
        ViewState["alert"] = userdata;
    }
}
```

here is my page_load and timer code. It runs a proc in my database counting the rows. The timer checdks every 5 secs and checks if the count is different. If it is the javascript is run and triggers the alert then resets the viewstate. I don't know if this is the cleanest way to do it but it works.